# adjust the x axis to show each bins value

Tags: r, plot, histogram

Across the bottom of the histogram I have time (in excel's numeric format) but I need to display the time much more often than it is currently showing.

```
hist(order$maxRequest.Date, main="Histogram", xlab="", breaks=3)
```

[image]

So instead of showing the days as `42200, 42400, 42600,...` across the bottom I want something like `42200,42300,42400,42500,...`

Comment: That's not excel weird format. That's numeric. You need to convert data to datetime format. `?asDate` or`?asPOSIXct` read about these.

Comment: You can add number of `breaks`. Isn't it obvious?

Comment: or maybe you want `axis(side=1, at=seq(42200,43000, 100), labels=seq(as.Date("2015/7/15"), by = "month", length.out = 36))`

Comment: I have the date in excels weird format on purpose. And yes adding breaks would be quite easy, however that does not help me. I need more detailed labels across the bottom. instead of showing labels every 200 days i would like to see a label for every 50 days or so, changing the bins does not let me control the labels.

Comment: I already posted an answer to that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can define your axis by adding a line after plotting the histogram;

```
hist(order$maxRequest.Date, main="Histogram", xlab="", breaks=3, xaxt = "n")
axis(side=1, at=seq(42200,43000, 100),
          labels=seq(as.Date(42200, origin =  '1899-12-30'),
                     as.Date(43000, origin =  '1899-12-30'), 
                                                            by = "100 days")) 
  #*note: Origin has been set to the above to match excel date
```

This also gives you labels in date format (*not-weird* as you call them) labels.

You may also want to increase `break = 6` if you want to make the bins smaller (and not just the labels more frequent).

If you also don't want the *Date Format*, you can use the same `seq` for the `labels` as well.

Comment: that looks like exactly what I was looking for, but i'm getting an error. Error in axis(side = 1, at = seq(42200, 43000, 100), labels = seq(as.Date("2015/7/15"),  : 
  'at' and 'labels' lengths differ, 9 != 36 Any thoughts on this error?

Comment: @Coopa either change 36 in `length.out` to 9 or use the updated answer.